# Custom spring boot security not applied

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm doing a MVC project with spring boot and spring security and jsp. I'm just training my spring and I have the same project running without spring boot. Currently I moved to springboot and when I start it , the custom security configuration is never applied.

I have no idea what is happening.

application.properties

```
# JDBC properties
#
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=springstudent
spring.datasource.password=springstudent

# Spring Data JPA properties
spring.data.jpa.repository.packages=com.crm.dao
spring.data.jpa.entity.packages-to-scan=com.crm.beans

#
# SECURITY JDBC properties
#
security.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_security_demo_bcrypt?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
security.datasource.username=springstudent
security.datasource.password=springstudent
security.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Configuration:

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class DemoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        // add a reference to our security data source

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("securityDataSource")
        private DataSource securityDataSource;


        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);

        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("aplicando configuracion");
            http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/employees/showForm*").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/employees/save*").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/employees/delete").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/employees/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/showMyLoginPage").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

        }


    }
```

Configuration:

```
 @Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"${spring.data.jpa.repository.packages}"})
public class DemoDataSourceConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource appDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.data.jpa.entity")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, DataSource appDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(appDataSource)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="security.datasource")
    public DataSource securityDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

POM.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.crm</groupId>
    <artifactId>Crm-Pet-Clinic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Crm-Pet-Clinic</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

            <!-- Add Spring Security Taglibs support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet, JSP and JSTL support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be an issue with the `application.properties` file. When you have multiple datasources defined, you need to use `jdbc-url` or `jdbcUrl` instead of `url`. Below is an example

```
# JDBC properties
# Change the below line to jdbc-url instead of url
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
# OR Change the below line to jdbcUrl instead of url
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=springstudent
spring.datasource.password=springstudent
```

Instead of `url` you need to provide it as the `jdbc-url` or as `jdbcUrl`. By default, this is what Spring looks for when creating the `DataSource` bean. Read [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-data-access) for more information on how the binding happens and how the aliases work under the hood for Spring. These same tutorials also have information on how to deal with situations like this if you prefer not to go with the default spring configurations.

And as a side note, with spring boot. You do not have to provide a `driver-class`. That is determined automatically.

> Spring Boot also provides a utility builder class, called
>   DataSourceBuilder, that can be used to create one of the standard data
>   sources (if it is on the classpath). The builder can detect the one to
>   use based on what’s available on the classpath. It also auto-detects
>   the driver based on the JDBC URL.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think this is not the problem. In fact in the second link you can see these properties with several custom names like app.datasource.* . Anyway, I tried but didn't work, it show an error because it doesn't find the url atribute.

Comment: @AntonioDiaz yeah, you dont have to change the name from app.datasource.* to spring.datasource.*. What I am saying is, use the jdbc-url instead or url. So it would look like `app.datasource.jdbc-url` in your case not `app.datasource.url`

Comment: Hi, I know, I've just wanted to say that  i hink this is not the problem because you can name this properties with a custom value. Anyway, I tried your solution and it's not running. It's getting  : 
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Comment: Can you post your pom file as well. Make sure you have  `mysql-connector-java` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` listed as dependencies in your project

Comment: They are added. I've edited the post in order to show you the pom.xml

Comment: As per my understanding, you need to provide the `spring.datasource.url` as `spring.datasource.jdbc-url` or as `spring.datasource.jdbcUrl`when you have more than one Datasource defined. And you don't have to provide the `security.datasource.driver-class-name` as spring automatically picks this up for you.  Do a `mvn clean install`. I ve updated the answer